How do I stop trigger error notiification email messages
How do I stop these messages?  I have not used this for years and I do not see where to resolve.  I click on the "click here" and it says that I have no triggers set up.
I click on the "click here" and it says that I have no triggers set up.
Email Message:
noreply-apps-scripts-notifications@google.com

Your script, camera-recordings-kitchen-cabinet, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.



Start
Function
Error Message
Trigger End




6/17/24, 12:09:21 AM India Standard Time
purgeGmail
Authorization is required to perform that action.
time-based



Sincerely,
Google Apps Script
Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. > Please do not reply to this message. (c) 2024 Google


Normally when I get those they include a link to the project that contains the triggers.  Perhaps you should contact google support

Suppose you use Google's multiple-account sign-in feature or have forwarded email messages from one account to another. In that case, you are likely having problems finding the script throwing this error message because you are not using the correct account.
In this case, look to the To field, then ensure you are opening https://script.google.com with that account.
